# facebook modify what a user sees for a specific user

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am wondering if it is possible to change what a user of facebook sees in comments. I cant seem to find anything on it.  I am pretty sure it is not possible, but I wanted to check here first.  Also if so can someone point me to some info on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are looking for is the ability to control the actual comment content displayed in pages displayed on the facebook.com domain (so user A sees one thing but user B sees another thing based on some rules you control) then the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure with your question. but, in my opinion. You asked about how to edit comments after posted.

if like this, I'm not sure it's possible to do. Although we delete our first comments which we want to edit, it's already send as notify to your friend's email. So, it's like "talk to people in real world".

Comment: sorry I wasn't clearer, but it was the answer that Femi left that was what I was looking for